# How to create a masonry layout in react native using flat list

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to create a masonry layout layout with infinity scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Is the size of all the items always the same? As seen in the image

Comment: @BrayanSalazar no .I want something like this -> https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-zNDW26bfAhVFwI8KHXtqAGcQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Freactnativeexample.com%2Feasy-react-native-layout-grid-for-the-dumb%2F&psig=AOvVaw3R2qcK6lLqapDann-PUUT-&ust=1545130996814838

Answer (score 3):

As per the react native docs, Flatlist wont support masonry layout.

The numColumns section in Flatlist doc suggests, "Items should all be the same height - masonry layouts are not supported."

Please refer, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#numcolumns

Answer (score 1):

Using a 'platlist' only creates a list of regular sizes.

If you want to create a 'masonry' type layout, it is recommended that you use 'npm' related to the 'masonry-list'.

https://www.npmjscom/package/react-native-masonry-list

Answer (score 0):

Just use a flat list and make one row display the two images side by side

Comment: I did it.but the height of the two layouts its same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,i used react-native-masonry-layout

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Image, Text, View, Dimensions, RefreshControl, Alert } from "react-native";
const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const columnWidth = (width - 10) / 2 - 10;
import Masonry from 'react-native-masonry-layout';

export class App extends Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    let data = [
      {
        image: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg",
        text: "Test",
        key: 1,
      },
      {
        image: "https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/cc/us/en/products/creativecloud/stock/stock-riverflow1-720x522.jpg.img.jpg",
        text: "Image1",
        key: 1,
      },
      {
        image: "https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg",
        text: "Image1",
        key: 1,
      },
      {
        image: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/child-hands-formig-heart-shape-picture-id951945718?k=6&m=951945718&s=612x612&w=0&h=ih-N7RytxrTfhDyvyTQCA5q5xKoJToKSYgdsJ_mHrv0=",
        text: "Image3",
        key: 1,
      },
      {
        image: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/46/da/e5/46dae512e375bee2664a025507da8795.jpg",
        text: "Image1",
        key: 1,
      },
    ]

    let last = data.length
    let new_data = []
    data.map((item, index) => {
      let height = 100
      if (index === 0) {
        console.log(index, ":", 150)
      } else if (index === last - 1 && last % 2 == 0) {
        console.log(index, ":", 150)
      }
      else {
        console.log(index, ":", 250)
        height = 200
      }

      new_data.push(
        {
          image: item.image,
          height: height,
          text: item.text,
        }
      )

      if (index === last - 1 && last % 2 !== 0) {
        new_data.push(
          {
            image: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c9/22/68/c92268d92cf2dbf96e3195683d9e14fb.png",
            height: 100,
            text: "No data "
          }
        )
      }

    })

    
    this.refs.list.addItems(new_data);
  }


  render() {
    return <View style={{ display: 'flex', flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#EEE" }}>
      <Masonry
        style={{ flex: 1, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "red" }}
        columns={2} ref="list"
        containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}
        renderItem={item => <View
          style={{
            margin: 5,
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            borderRadius: 5,
            overflow: "hidden",
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#dedede"
          }}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={{ height: item.height }} />

          <Text style={{ padding: 5, color: "#444" }}>{item.text}</Text>
        </View>} />
    </View>
  }
}

export default App
```

Referance : https://github.com/manyuanrong/react-native-masonry-layout
Enjoy!...

[image: Here is a demo image]